# JavaScript Namespaces and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

all. I think I am having a syntax issue here trying to access jQuery inside of my JavaScript namespace. I know there is nothing wrong with the code as it works when not in namespace. Also it should be noted that the sorting functions work. It's just the filtering which accesses my jQuery. Currently it just re-renders the table as it when I try to filter. Here is the code. Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>For the love of cats and JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input id="filter" class="" name="filter" type="text"  value="coffeePreference" onfocus="if (this.value == 'MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT.coffeePreference') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') " /></br></br>
    <input id="filter2" class="" name="filter2" type="text"  value="breed" onfocus="if (this.value == 'breed') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') " /></br></br>
    <div id="catTable"></div>
    <script>

        var MYCATSPACE = MYCATSPACE || {};
        var sortCountry;
        var sortBreed;
        var sortCoffee;

        $('input').keyup(function(e) {
            var timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                criteria = this.value;
                $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats){MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT.filterCats(cats, criteria);});
            }.bind(this), 185);
        });

        $("#filter2").keyup(function(e) {
            var timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                criteria = this.value;
                $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats){MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT.filterCats2(cats, criteria);});
            }.bind(this), 185);
        }); 
            MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT = {


            renderData: function(cats){
                var output='<table id="indextable" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">';
                output+="<thead>"
                output+="<tr>";
                output+="<th> HeadShot </th>";
                output+="<th><button onclick='MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT.getSortedBreedData()'>Breed</button></th>";
                output+="<th><button onclick='MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT.getSortedCountryData()'>Country</button></th>";
                output+="<th><button onclick='MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT.getSortedCoffeeData()'>CoffeePreference</button></th>";
                output+="</tr>";
                output+="</thead>"

                for (var i in cats) {
                    output+="<tbody>" 

                    output+="<tr>";
                    output+="<td><img src='" + cats[i].picture+"' alt='missing cat picture'></td>"
                    output+="<td>" + cats[i].breed + "</td>"
                    output+="<td>" + cats[i].country + "</td>"
                    output+="<td>" + cats[i].coffeePreference + "</td>"
                    output+="</tr>";
                    output+="</tbody>" 

                }
                output+="</table>";
                document.getElementById("catTable").innerHTML=output;
            },     

            getData: function(){       
                $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
                    var cats = cats;
                    MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT.renderData(cats);    
                });
            },

            getSortedCountryData: function(){  
                $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
                    var cats = cats;
                    if (sortCountry!=true)
                        MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT.sortData(cats,'country',1);
                    else 
                        MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT.sortData(cats,'country',-1);
                        sortCountry ^= true;   
                });
            },            

            getSortedBreedData: function(){  
                $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
                    var cats = cats;
                    if (sortCountry!=true)
                        MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT.sortData(cats,'breed',1);
                    else 
                        MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT.sortData(cats,'breed',-1);
                        sortCountry ^= true;   
                });
            },

            getSortedCoffeeData: function(){  
                $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
                    var cats = cats;
                    if (sortCountry!=true)
                        MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT.sortData(cats,'coffeePreference',1);
                    else 
                        MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT.sortData(cats,'coffeePreference',-1);
                        sortCountry ^= true;   
                });
            },

            sortData: function(cats, element, direction){
                switch(element) {
                    case 'breed':
                    var sortedData = cats.sort(function(a,b){return (a.breed < b.breed) ? -1*direction : 1*direction;});
                    MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT.renderData(cats);
                    break;
                    case 'country':
                    var sortedData = cats.sort(function(a,b){return (a.country < b.country) ? -1*direction : 1*direction;});
                    MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT.renderData(cats);
                    break;
                    case 'coffeePreference':
                    var sortedData = cats.sort(function(a,b){return (a.coffeePreference < b.coffeePreference) ? -1*direction : 1*direction;});
                    MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT.renderData(cats);
                    default:
                    MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT.renderData(cats);
                }

            },

            filterCats: function(cats, criteria){
                //var filteredData = cats.filter(function(c){return c.breed.toUpperCase().indexOf(criteria.toUpperCase()) !== -1;});   
                var filteredData = cats.filter(function(c){return c.coffeePreference.toUpperCase().indexOf(criteria.toUpperCase()) === 0 ;});    
                MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT.renderData(cats);
            },

            filterCats2: function(cats, criteria){
                //var filteredData = cats.filter(function(c){return c.breed.toUpperCase().indexOf(criteria.toUpperCase()) !== -1;});   
                var filteredData = cats.filter(function(d){return d.breed.toUpperCase().indexOf(criteria.toUpperCase()) === 0 ;});    
                MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT.renderData(cats);
            }

        }  

        MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT.getData();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing syntactically wrong with your code. [You can check that using online syntax validators.](http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html)

The reason your filter functions aren't working is because they aren't being applied to your HTML:

```
filterCats: function(cats, criteria){  
    var filteredData = cats.filter(function(c){return c.coffeePreference.toUpperCase().indexOf(criteria.toUpperCase()) === 0 ;});    

    // Problem Lies Here. Change cats to filteredData
    MYCATSPACE.SUBCAT.renderData(cats);
},
```